# Shouldn't there be "bogie" instead of "bogey" in this sentence?

Tags: synonyms, orthography

I read a sentence in a chapter in my book which was:

> A bogey of a train that was returning from Ayodhya and was full of Karsevaks was set on fire.

I didn't find any dictionary describing the word "bogey" in the sense it has been used in here. (I looked in [Oxford Dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bogie); there was no variant spelling of "bogie" in this dictionary.) So I want to know whether it is acceptable to use the word "bogey" as a variant of "bogie".

Comment: What dictionary were you looking in? Merriam-Webster has alternate spellings for both [bogey](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bogey) and [bogie](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bogie).

Comment: @Peter But not bogey = 4-wheel truck (of a train) under 'bogey'. 'ODO', CED, Collins, M-W, Macmillan and AHD don't have this sense for 'bogey' under 'bogey'; one has to look under 'bogie'.

Comment: [Oxford dictionaries](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bogie) There was no variant spelling of "bogie" in this dictionary.

Comment: Yes, but under *bogie*, M-W says *"less commonly, bogey."* On the other hand, it's clear they consider *bogie* the preferred spelling for this sense.

Comment: @Peter It shows that dictionaries aren't even self-consistent.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a cross-post of the identical question at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/216885/shouldnt-there-be-bogie-instead-of-bogey-in-this-sentence), which has already received an accepted answer.

Comment: But the accepted answer also says 'In short, there's probably no point in a *learners'* site trying to lay down the law about "correct" spelling for any given use of these 5 words', so presumably a site for *experienced linguists* might do that.

Comment: I added OP's comment into the question to help it from being closed for lack of research. Unfortunately, the link seems to have rotted. (It was to the old Lexico site.)

Answer (score 3):

Multiple books reporting on this historical incident do in fact use the spelling *bogie*.

From Siddharth Varadarajan, [*Gujarat, the Making of a Tragedy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1kc9GmFWePUC&pg=PA45&dq=bogie+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm2q-r963-AhUEGTQIHYZvAXsQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=bogie%20Ayodhya%20%20fire&f=false) (2002):

> How and why was the Sabarmati Express set on fire? ... An experiment conducted in June by the Forensic Science Laboratory (FSL), Ahmedabad, showed that the fire could only have been caused by pouring inflammable liquid from inside the coach and then starting the fire in the bogie.the coach and then starting the fire in the **bogie**.

From John Hawley & Vasudh Narayanan, [*The Life of Hinduism*](https://books.google.com/books?id=4-s325pdqW8C&pg=PA5&dq=bogie+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm2q-r963-AhUEGTQIHYZvAXsQ6AF6BAgFEAI#v=onepage&q=bogie%20Ayodhya%20%20fire&f=false) (2006):

> Fifty-eight people died in a fire that swept through one **bogie** of that train while it stood in Godhra station. Most early reports said a Muslim mob on the platform had torched the **bogie** as a Hindu-Muslim argument escalated out of control. ...
>
> But it's far from certain that Muslims relly did torch the train in Godhra in response to insults from Hindi-chauvinist pilgrims. Early investigations reported that the fire actually started t a particular seat inside the **bogie**—possibly ignite by a kerosene burner.

From Desppande, [*Gujarat Riots: Th True Story*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qY7xBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA52&dq=A+bogie+of+a+train+that+was+returning+from+Ayodhya+and+was+full+of+Karsevaks+was+set+on+fire.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_oMSd863-AhV5MDQIHVUoCx0Q6AF6BAgJEAI#v=onepage&q=A%20bogie%20of%20a%20train%20that%20was%20returning%20from%20Ayodhya%20and%20was%20full%20of%20Karsevaks%20was%20set%20on%20fire.&f=false) (2014):

> The local administration did not respond with speed to the Godhra carnage. The police remained a passive spectator and hesitated to use force against the miscreants. It made no attempt to apprehend the leaders of the mob that indulged in burning alive innocent pilgrims returning from Ayodhya.
>
> ...
>
> "They stormed inside the women's **bogie**, and before we could react, they set the entire **bogie** on fire. Some of us managed to escape, but a number of our sisters got trapped...it was horrifying." said Hetal Patel, a member of Durga Vahini.

From A. P. Durai, [*Pursuit of Law and Order*](https://books.google.com/books?id=zIZVCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT346&dq=A+bogie+of+a+train+that+was+returning+from+Ayodhya+and+was+full+of+Karsevaks+was+set+on+fire.&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi_oMSd863-AhV5MDQIHVUoCx0Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=A%20bogie%20of%20a%20train%20that%20was%20returning%20from%20Ayodhya%20and%20was%20full%20of%20Karsevaks%20was%20set%20on%20fire.&f=false) (2015):

> Apparently, Lalu Prasad wanted to show his appreciation or gratitude to me and when he became the Railway Minister, he spoke to me twice and asked me to take up an inquiry into the Godhra incident (2002) where a sleeper **bogie** in which Karsevaks and pilgrims returning from Ayodhya had been set fire to, allegedly by a Muslim mob, killing fifty-eight passengers.

from Anand Teltumbde, [*Hindutva and Dalits: Perspectives for Understanding Communal Praxis*](https://books.google.com/books?id=sRzHDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR25&dq=%22were+burnt+alive+in+a+mysterious+fire+in+the+bogie%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFvZiR9q3-AhVAJzQIHSJMAwAQ6AF6BAgHEAI#v=onepage&q=%22were%20burnt%20alive%20in%20a%20mysterious%20fire%20in%20the%20bogie%22&f=false) (2020):

> Just after four months, an incident at Godhra took place in which 59 kar sevaks (those who offer services for free to a religious cause) were burnt alive in a mysterious fire in the **bogie** of Sabarmati Express, in which they were travelling, on 27 February 2002. They were returning after a religious ceremony at the site of the demolished Babri Masjid at Ayodhya.

Altogether, more than twenty confirmable sources appear in a Google Books search for "Gujarat" + "bogie" + "fire" with the spelling *bogie*.

However, a comparable search for "Gujarat" + bogey" + "fire" yields even more confirmable matches—not a lot more, but a total in the middle twenties, not counting duplicate entries in CUET and NCERT test preparation books.

For example, from Ram Snarma, [*Gujarat Holocaust: Communalism in the Land of Gandhi*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-WhuAAAAMAAJ&q=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&dq=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic6bmY_a3-AhXEM0QIHb9fBIE4HhDoAXoECAoQAg) (2002) [combined snippets]:

> It is obvious to anyone the the Godhra incident was premeditated. One can not target a specific **bogey** in a train without the support of a chain of informers. You cannot, without meticulous planning, stop the train at a specific spot, surround it, lock the doors, hi the occupants with iron rods and then torch the **bogey** while another section of the rioters prevent help like fire engine from arriving.

From Ram Puniyani, [*Communalism: An Illustrated Primer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZWgMAQAAMAAJ&q=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&dq=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9wsyV_q3-AhUJKEQIHfWbB9s4KBDoAXoECAQQAg) (2004) [combined snippets]:

> ***Myth:*** Narendra Modi correctly points out that burning of bogey if Sabarmati train was an act planned by, International terrorism, ISI and local Muslims.
>
> ***Fact:*** On 27th of February the **bogey** 5-6 of Sabarmati train was put to fire killing fifty-seven unfortunate lives. There are different conflicting versions of the episode. The minimum, which can be inferred before the true facts come out from the inquiry commission report are that the **bogey** was full of Ram Sevaks returning from the pilgrimage to Ayodhya where different rituals around Ram Shila Puja were going on.

From Chitralekha, [*Ordinary People, Extraordinary Violence: Naxalites and Hindu Extremists in India*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nOYJEAAAQBAJ&pg=PT85&dq=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwic6bmY_a3-AhXEM0QIHb9fBIE4HhDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=bogey%20Ayodhya%20%20fire&f=false) (2012):

> While the presence of such 'big people' [as Sadhvi Rithambara] was important, Archana Behen felt, to inspire the girl, the camp had also roped in Durga Vahini associates who were in the ill fated S-6 **bogey** of the Sabarmati Express that was set on fire by a Muslim mob in Godhra a year before.

From Rositta Valiyamattam, [*Personal and National Destinies in Independent India: A Study of Selected Indian English Novels*](https://books.google.com/books?id=-uS2DQAAQBAJ&pg=PA128&dq=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx1-KH_a3-AhUaJkQIHX_DDfc4FBDoAXoECAgQAg#v=onepage&q=bogey%20Ayodhya%20%20fire&f=false) (2016):

> On 27 February 2002, the Sabarmati express full of volunteers returning from Ayodhya, halted at the Godhra station in Gujarat, where an altercation took place between passengers and Muslim vendors. Shortly after the train left the station, a **bogey** caught fire, killing fifty-eight volunteers.

And from Ramachandra Guha, [*India After Gandhi: The History of the World's Largest Democracy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=AW4sDwAAQBAJ&pg=RA12-PR12&dq=bogey+Ayodhya++fire&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjx1-KH_a3-AhUaJkQIHX_DDfc4FBDoAXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=bogey%20Ayodhya%20%20fire&f=false) (2017):

> It is also beyond dispute that the incident at the station was sparked by *kar sevaks* taunting Muslim vendors. What remains unclear is the cause of the fire afterwards. The VHP claimed that it was the handiwork of a Muslim mob. On the other hand, forensic evidence suggested that it originated inside the **bogey**, accidentally and was probably the result of a gas cylinder or kerosene stove accidentally catching fire.

---

***Conclusions***

It appears from comments posted by the person who asked the question and by Edwin Ashworth and Peter Shor that *bogie* is the more common spelling in Indian English for the term when used to refer to a railway carriage. Nevertheless—at least in the case of the Godhra disaster—the variant spelling *bogey* is by no means uncommon, in Indian sources as well as in accounts from outside the country.

It therefore seems fair to conclude that use of the spelling *bogey* to mean "railway carriage" is acceptable in Indian English, even though the spelling *bogie* may be preferred by some writers and some reference works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it should be *bogie* instead of *bogey*.

Actually the *bogie* of a train or truck does refer to the undercarriage.

*Bogey* is from a set of words relating to some alarming manifestation. Similar to *bugbear* or *bugaboo*. Likely from the Scandinavian for a big man or *bugge*. It came to mean one stroke over par after a Major Wellman claimed his bad luck at golf one day was from playing against a Bogeyman or phantom on the course.*

I am not surprised in the misuse of one spelling over another since the words sound just alike and few people could tell you about an undercarriage. You might use one for the other and have only this group to tell you how wrong it is but they did not begin as variants.

- Dictionary of Word Origins, Ayto

Comment: In that sentence, *bogie* does not to refer to an undercarriage but a train car. See the [Oxford Dictionary Online](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bogie) "1.1 *Indian* A railway carriage." Ayodhya is a city in India.